# Trying to create a PHP foreach loop that loops through an array to call an API and output into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, api, loops

I've just added a loop to code I already have working. I'm pretty sure what's giving me the trouble, and that is one of the following pieces of code:

**First I have:**

```
$teams = array(ARI, ATL, BAL, BUF, CAR, CHI, CIN, CLE, DAL, DEN, DET, GB, HOU, IND, JAC, KC, MIA, MIN, NE, NO, NYG, NYJ, OAK, PHI, PIT, SD, SEA, SF, STL, TB, TEN, WAS);

foreach ($teams as $value) {

$query_string = 'api_key='.$api_key.'&team=$value'; // Change team/month
```

Is this the right way to set up `$query_string` to a `$value` that's changing as the loop runs?

**Later inside the loop I have:**

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $value . _GAMES ( ".  // Creating a new table for each team
```

Is this the right way to concatenate the `$value` variable being changed by the loop with the rest of what I want the table name to be? (i.e. I want the first loop to create the table `ARI_GAMES`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `$query_string` to

```
$teams = array('ARI', 'ATL', 'BAL', 'BUF');
foreach ($teams as $value) {

$query_string = 'api_key='.$api_key.'&team='.$value;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Thanks for the quick answer! I'm getting the following error from Terminal: Could not create table: Unknown database 'ari'           
 - that must be referring to the first entry in the array, ARI.
When I run this on PhpFiddle, I get the following error message E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant ARI - assumed 'ARI' -- at line 9
(line 9 is where I define the $teams array.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think my dear friend you need little more to learn regarding `PHP arrays`.
First your `$teams` array must be an array with strings which are the names of the teams as follows(**Note:** I have shorten the list of teams array):

```
$teams = array("ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "CHI", "CIN", "CLE", "DAL", "DEN", "DET");
```

So then you need to understand how the PHP concatenation works. For an example, it goes as follows:

```
$someVar = 5;
$concatenateVar = $someVar.' myOtherStringHere '.$someVar;
echo $concatenatedVar;
```

will print out following line:

```
5 myOtherStringHere 5
```

However I've written the required code specifically for your question. Please try to understand it and learn from it.

```
<?php
    $teams = array("ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "CHI", "CIN", "CLE", "DAL", "DEN", "DET");

    $api_key = "API_KEY_HERE";

    foreach ($teams as $value) {
        echo "start of another foreach-loop round<br/>";
        $query_string = 'api_key = '.$api_key.' team = '.$value; 
            echo $query_string;
        echo "<br/>";
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $value._GAMES ( ";  // Creating a new table for each team
            echo $sql;
        echo "<br/>end of a foreach-loop round<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Kasun! That was really helpful. I'm now getting the following error: Could not add JSON data to table: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'nfl_game_id' at row 1

When I echo the API call, this is what the data looks like:
    [{"nfl_game_id":2009081350,"team":"ARI","opponent":"PIT","totfd":22,"totyds":329,"pyds":259,"ryds":70,"pen":4,"penyds":27,"trnovr":2,"pt":6,"ptyds":266,"ptavg":37}, .....

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hey its helpful then you should at least up-vote or may be accept as the answer! :-) and also put your above question in another Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Using quotes and curly brackets will be good

```
$teams = array('ARI', 'ATL', 'BAL', 'BUF');
foreach ($teams as $value) {
    $query_string = "api_key={$api_key}&team={$value}";

    //sql
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$value}_GAMES (.... ";
}
```